# Add text to placeholder in a jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add text to the placeholder box that shows while dragging the sortable item. is there a function in jQuery's UI that I'm missing? Right now I'm trying to `.append()` the info, but it's not working.

Here's the jQuery function:

```
//Sortable Function - Edit Wizard
$(function () {

    //add text to placeholder box
    if ($('.ui-state-highlight').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-state-highlight').append('<span>MOVE HERE</span>');
    };


    $(".sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        //revert: true,
        grid: [20, 20],
        handle: '.editMove',
        opacity: 0.6,
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 80,
        zIndex: 10
    });
    $(".sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

### Edit

I guess there needs to be some `.live()` change function for the `.append()`?

Comment: your is statemnt return True or False and not jquery object, so $(this) must be undefined
you can use $('.ui-state-highlight:visible') to use $(this) if you'd like

Comment: Edited. Still doesn't work. Problem is the '.ui-state-highlight' div is not visible until you start to drag the sortable item...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that even though your conditional statement is looking for '.ui-state-highlight' to be visible it doesn't mean that '$(this)' is referring to that element, unless there is more to the jQuery that isn't shown here. I included a small jsfiddle below that helps explain, hope this helps!

**EDIT:** I included a new fiddle that I am 99% sure is what you're looking for.

I set-up a sortable list using the example straight off of the [jQuery UI - Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder) page, and I took a look at the Events built in with it. There is an event called start that binds an event when sorting starts, I used that to append the text to '.ui-state-highlight'

http://jsfiddle.net/6PrvC/

Comment: Thanks. Why wouldn't (this) work? In any event, this is still not working. The .ui-state-highlight div is hidden on page load. It's only shown when you start to drag the sortable jQuery UI item. I think that's the problem I'm running into with it not being displayed...

Comment: Aghhhh perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't notice the "sortcreate" event...Thanks! 1+

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the placeholder from the start callback, like this:

```
$('#my-sortable').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.html('Placeholder Content!');
    }
});
```